# Join matching lines

Tags: regex, awk, sed

Given this sample file

```
$ cat infile.txt
foo
  hello
bar
  world
baz
qux
```

I would like to join all the lines not starting with a space, to end up with
this

```
foo:bar:baz:qux
```

I tried this

```sh
$ sed ':a;N;s/\n/:/;ba' infile.txt
foo:  hello:bar:  world:baz:qux
```

but it joins all the lines. For the purpose of this question I prefer a sed only
solution.

After reading the answers and comments I have these working commands

```sh
$ sed '/ /!H;$!d;x;s/\n//;s//:/g' infile.txt
foo:bar:baz:qux

$ awk '!/ /{printf s++?":"$0:$0}' infile.txt
foo:bar:baz:qux
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sh
sed '/^ /d; H; ${ x; s/\n/:/g; s/^://; p; }; d'
```

The first part `/^ /d;` deletes lines starting with a blank. `H` appends the pattern space to the hold space after a newline. The `${ x; s/\n/:/g; s/^://; p; };` deals with the last line.  It swaps the pattern and hold space, replaces newlines with colons, removes the first colon, and prints the result.  The final `d` deletes the lines so that you only see the final output.

Comment: @Steven Penny, check this one `sed -n '/^ /!H;${x;s/\n/:/g;s/.//p;}' YourFile`

Comment: Perhaps `sed '/^\s/d;H;$!d;x;s/\n//;s//:/g' file` might be a little less busy.

Comment: @potong if you want to put that as an answer I will upvote it

Answer (score 2):

Using sed only:

```
~$ sed -ne '{/^[^ ]/{H};${x;s/\n/:/g;s/^://;p}}' infile.txt
foo:bar:baz:qux
```

For each line, append to the hold buffer if it doesn't start with a space.
At the end, exchange pattern and hold buffer, and substitute `\n` with `:`, then care of the possibly first `:` and prints.

A little less ugly:

```
~$ sed -ne '/^ /!H;${x;s/\n/:/g;s/^://;p}' infile.txt
foo:bar:baz:qux
```

And using speed optimization (according to [this file](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/09/sed1line.txt), thanks @StevenPenny)

```
~$ sed -ne '/^ /!H;${x;/\n/s///;s//:/g;p}' infile.txt
```

Append to hold buffer except if starts with spaces. At the last line, bring hold buffer to pattern and if it matches `/\n/`, delete the first one (`s///`), and substitute the others with `:` (`s//:/g/`).

---

If you don't mind piping `sed` commands:

```
~$ sed '/^ /d' infile.txt | sed ':a;N;s/\n/:/;ba'
foo:bar:baz:qux
```

Just delete lines starting with spaces and then join the lines.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler otherwise the `H` will append a new line and then the first line, producing: `:foo:bar:baz:qux`

Comment: OK; but what if the first line starts with a space?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Then there is a problem indeed…

Answer (score 2):

I know only you're looking for `sed` only answers, but I am posting an awk command just to show how un-cryptic `awk` is as compared to `sed`:

```
awk -v ORS=: '/^[^ ]/' file
foo:bar:baz:qux:
```

If you don't want last `:` then:

```
awk -v ORS=: '/^[^ ]/{s=s $0 ORS} END{printf "%s\n", substr(s, 1, length(s)-1)}' file
foo:bar:baz:qux
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ grep -e '^[^ ]' infile.txt | tr '\n' ':' | sed 's/.$/\n/'
foo:bar:baz:qux
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
sed -nr '/^[^ ]/p' test.txt | sed ':a;N;s/\n/:/;ba'
```

Comment: Before your edit your answer added a trailing `:`. Now it is better, -1 retracted :)

Comment: Thanks @LutzHorn for reasoning that out so i could improve :)

Answer (score 0):

**With sed:**

```
sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/:/g; s/ [^:]*://g' File
```

Here, `:a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g` is to remove all newlines, which would give `foo:  hello:bar:  world:baz:qux` . Then `s/ [^:]*://g` to remove from `space to :`. This will not work everytime, if other `:`s and spaces are present in each line :-) . As per your example, it will though.

**With awk:**

```
awk '!/^ /{if(a){a=a ":" $0}else{a=a $0}} END{print a}' File
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, ok, this is not sed... Anyway;

```
perl -p0e 's/\n( .*\n)*/:/g'
```

- -0   slurp input file
- -p   print "it" after processing

(And thank you all for the brilliant sed and awk solutions presented!!)